# free cdn for custom javascript and css files

Tags: iis, cdn

I am looking for a no nonsense free cdn solution for my iis/.net website where i could store all my custom javascript , css and fonts etc to increase my site performance.

Is there any good free cdn available for such purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Go for CloudFlare (https://www.cloudflare.com), its free and very easy to setup (only takes few minutes to setup). Its works on DNS, so you don't have to do any code change as well.

thanks